# can someone help fix my code? about opening and closing switches

Tags: java

it seems that I have a lot of problems with { } so if someone can help me cortect it, it will be wonderful!
the code ment to check the date and based on special years (every 4 years, when febuary gets 29 days) will calculate the new date

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class next_date {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int year,month,day;System.out.println("enter the day number please: ");
        Scanner reader= new Scanner (System.in);
        day= reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter the month number please: ");
        month= reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter the year number please: ");
        year= reader.nextInt();
        boolean check_m;
        check_m= ((year%4)==0);

        switch (month){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("January");
            if (day<=31) {
                System.out.println("Date Ok!");
                if ((day+1)>31)
                    month++;
                day=1;
                System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);

                else {
                    day++;
                    System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);}
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("not ok...");
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("February");
            if (check_m){
                if (day<=29){
                    System.out.println("Date Ok!");
                    if ((day+1)>29)
                        month++;
                    day=1;
                    System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
                    else {
                        day++;
                        System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);}
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("not ok...");
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (day<=28){
                System.out.println("Date Ok!");
                if ((day+1)>28)
                    month++;
                day=1;
                System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
                else {
                    day++;
                    System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
                }
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("not ok...");
                break;
            }
        case 3:
            System.out.println("March"); 
            if (day<=31) {
                System.out.println("Date Ok!");
                if ((day+1)>31)
                    month++;
                day=1;
                System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
                else {
                    day++;
                    System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);}
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("not ok...");
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println( "April");
            if (day<=30) {
                System.out.println("Date Ok!");
                if ((day+1)>30)
                    month++;
                day=1;
                System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
                else{
                    day++;
                    System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);}
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("not ok...");
            }
            break;
        case 5:System.out.println( "May");
        if (day<=31){
            System.out.println("Date Ok!");
            if ((day+1)>31)
                month++;
            day=1;
            System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
            else{
                day++;
                System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);}
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("not ok...");
        }
        break;
        case 6:  System.out.println( "June");
        if (day<=30){
            System.out.println("Date Ok!");
            if ((day+1)>30)
                month++;
            day=1;
            System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
            else{
                day++;
                System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);}
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("not ok...");
        }
        break;
        case 7: System.out.println( "July");
        if (day<=31){
            System.out.println("Date Ok!");
            if ((day+1)>31)
                month++;
            day=1;
            System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
            else{
                day++;
                System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);}
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("not ok...");
        }     
        break;
        case 8:  System.out.println( "Augoust");
        if (day<=30){
            System.out.println("Date Ok!");
            if ((day+1)>30)
                month++;
            day=1;
            System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
            else{
                day++;
                System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);}
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("not ok...");
        }     
        break;
        case 9:  System.out.println( "September");
        if (day<=31){
            System.out.println("Date Ok!");
            if ((day+1)>31)
                month++;
            day=1;
            System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
            else{
                day++;
                System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);}
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("not ok...");
        }     
        break;
        case 10: System.out.println( "October");
        if (day<=30){
            System.out.println("Date Ok!");
            if ((day+1)>30)
                month++;
            day=1;
            System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
            else{
                day++;
                System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);}
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("not ok...");
        }     
        break;
        case 11: System.out.println( "November");
        if (day<=31){
            System.out.println("Date Ok!");
            if ((day+1)>31)
                month++;
            day=1;
            System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
            else{
                day++;
                System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);}
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("not ok...");
        }     
        break;
        case 12: System.out.println( "December");
        if (day<=30){
            System.out.println("Date Ok!");
            if ((day+1)>30)
                month=1;
            day=1;
            year++;
            System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
            else{
                day++;
                System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);}
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("not ok...");
        }     
        break;
        default: System.out.println("Invalid month");
        break;




        }
```

Comment: any IDE should be of good help.

Comment: You could have downloaded some IDE and use it.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this section :

```
case 1: System.out.println("January");
     if (day<=31){
            System.out.println("Date Ok!");
            if ((day+1)>31)
                month++;
                day=1;
                System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
                else{
                    day++;
                System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);}
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("not ok...");
        }
     break;
```

Based on your indentation, it looks like you want multiple statements to be executed when `(day<=31)` is true, but without surrounding them with braces, only `month++` will be called.

```
case 1: System.out.println("January");
        if (day<=31) {
            System.out.println("Date Ok!");
            if ((day+1)>31) {
                month++;
                day=1;
                System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
            } else {
                day++;
                System.out.println(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("not ok...");
        }
        break;
```

Properly indenting your entire code will help you find missing braces or braces located in the wrong place.